# WebpackHotUpdate not defined Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Recently when building our application my team and I came across an error with webpackHotUpdate.

What currently happens is we build and run the application using Local settings in Visual Studio. The working app opens as usual and everything works. However when we apply a change while the app is running. You can see a save was registered as the console window runs however the browser does not refresh. When one refreshes the browser window the change is not registered and the following error appears in the console:

[image: Error 1]

This is linked to this file in the console:

[image: Error 2]

None of my research online seems to help. I am fairly new to Angular as well so I really am stuck now.

Does anyone have any suggestions that might help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @JamesPoulose no I don't think we ever found a solution. We ended up starting a new version of the project using the angular CLI with dotnet. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens only when you try to run Angular CLI also from Visual Studio 2017.This looks like a problem in the way Visual Studio 2017 performs the HMR (Hot Module Replacement) process. There are two options i tried

1. Disable `HMR` ny removing the switch from `ng serve` in
   `package.config`
2. Run the Angular CLI separately

I chose the second option as HMR was important for me.

Comment: Thank you, yes I also needed `HMR` so I think if you are not running a complicated project then the second option will work everytime, thanks for the answer.